# Facebook Cannot message users who are not admins, developers or tester

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

This question has been asked before, I got that. However, this case which is happening to me is weird.

I am testing my application which is created on Facebook.

> - The application is still on the development mode (not public yet)
> - The role of application has been distributed/shared to other Facebook accounts, I tried with all of roles (admin/dev/tester).
> - I am using the admin/dev account to make a message to my App fanpage via Messenger.
> - Everything worked well until today, it suddenly stoped working and threw the error message:

```
Cannot message users who are not admins, developers or testers of the app until pages_messaging permission is reviewed and the app is live.
```

I have no idea what's wrong. I tried different accounts with the same method, add testing account into app dashboard and approve the request, try to send a message and it was the same.

The error message seems falsy, because the account that I sent the message has already been added into the dev/tester pool of my app (the request has been approved and the app has been listed and been accessible for the tester account).

I cannot find the way to post an issue for FB dev to look into, so my only chance is posting this here.

Any help is appreciated.

[Facebook API 2.10](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api/)

Comment: The problem has been resolved itself. API starts working again on another day. I guess this was some kinds of their bug & they have fixed it.